# AngularJS - Simulate .prev() using jqLite only?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In `angular.element` there is only a `next()` method but `prev()`. Is there any way to simulate the behavior of `prev()` with Angular/jqLite only?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use native DOM api to get previous/next sibling:

```
var prevNode = element[0].previousElementSibling;
var prev = angular.element(prevNode); // optional

var nextNode = element[0].nextElementSibling;
var next = angular.element(nextNode); // optional
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an angularjs expert but I think that you can write a code like (not tested...):

```
function prevOf(yourElement) {
  var parent = yourElement.parent();
  var children = parent.children();

  var prev;
  for (var i = 1; i < children.length; i++){
    if (children[i] === yourElement[0]) {
      prev = children[i-1];
    }
  }

  return prev;
}
```